# Safe typecasting inside return

Tags: c++

Inside my code I am typecasting a variable before I return it (C++).

Is it safe to do so, or should I typecast first and then return the value?

Currently :

```
return NumericType (r_endoftheScale);
```

Or should I change it to

```
NumericType r_endoftheScale;
r_endoftheScale=NumericType (w_endoftheScale);
return r_endoftheScale;
```

Comment: Assuming that the returned type can masquerade successfully as the real type, then it should be safe; without seeing the types involved it's impossible to say for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two variants are equivalent and interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in how you do it.

If the function returns `NumericType`, it should convert automatically by constructing an instance of `NumericType`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. The second one is just much longer than needed.

As a hint, you can (and should) initialize variables where they are declared.

```
NumericType r_endoftheScale = NumericType (w_endoftheScale);
return r_endoftheScale;
```

You might also consider the appropriateness of Hungarian notation.